# Count the total number of selected alphabet in a string with split function in Js

Tags: javascript

I am trying to count the total number of `p` from any string in js.

my `js` code:

```
var sp = "pappa";
var as = sp.split("p");
console.log(as.length);
```

But it says output: `4` in the console.

even I put an empty string inside `sp` it shows the value `1`. Why It starts counting from `1`?

Comment: `split` splits at the provides token to give you an array. If you print that array you would know why it returns 4.

Comment: It returns some empty strings also. Try `var as = sp.split("p").filter(a => !!a);`

Comment: Maybe `"pappa".split('').reduce((c,ch) => ch === 'p' ? c + 1 : c, 0);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As java script creates at least one empty set for every split function you use so if you want to get exact count of any alphabet you need to subtract 1 from the final value.

Answer (score 1):

The output is correct. If the separator in `split()` occurs in first or last position of the string, then empty string is returned. In your case, for separator 'p', `str.split('p')` returns an array `["", "a", "", "a"]` which is of length 4.

Answer (score 1):

as Kishor mentioned split returns an array, you can do something like this to achieve the desired behaviour:

```
var sp = "pappa";
var as = sp.split("p");
var as2 = as.join("");
console.log(as2.length);
// number of "p"s
console.log(sp.length - as2.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

simply put these line

```
    var sp = "pappa";
console.log((sp.match(/p/g)).length);
```